# Fade or change opacity of background image on scrolling

Tags: javascript, background-image, opacity

Is it possible to have the background image of a site to change its opacity from 50% to 100% on scrolling? How? Probably something with javascript.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 500);
  });
```

```html
<div class="custom"  >
 <div class="top"><img style="position: relative" src="http://goldenstatetannery.com/images/sunset-wild01.jpg"></div>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```